# How do I save the current URL state in Android WebView?

Tags: android, view, webview, savestate, android-configchanges

In the browser that comes with Android, when you rotate the phone, the `WebView` is not reloaded. I was wondering how to do this. I can save the current URL of the `Webview` and pass it to the next version of myself, but how do I do that with the whole `WebView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just using onConfigurationChange and kept the same WebView. Thanks,
    Isaac Waller

Comment: Hi,can send me the source or link in peastbin?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to register for the configChange in your Manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".WebContent" android:configChanges="orientation">
```